# Setup nginx as Github Pages frontend, with https enabled

Tags: nginx, github-pages

I wanted to use custom domain for Github Pages, with HTTPS enabled using my own certs(not a CloudFlare one).

According to Github Pages instruction, the first part is done by setting up a CNAME both in project root folder and DNS, but this way HTTPS is not supported: `https://example.github.io` with custom domain `example.com` is only accessible in `http://example.com`, `https://example.com` won't work.

Thus I'm thinking of nginx reverse proxy: remove CNAME file and DNS setting, let 3 links co-exist, redirect http custom domain to https one, forward requests of https one to `github.io` address.

However, result is not perfect: homepage and css(in /css/main.css !) are loaded correctly, all links are displayed normally, but click them will result in 301 and redirected to github.io.

My nginx version is 1.9.5, configuration for port 80:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name myblog.com;
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}
```

for 443:

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    server_name myblog.com;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/orz.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/orz.key;
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security max-age=31536000;

    location / {
        proxy_pass https://example.github.io;
        proxy_set_header Host example.github.io;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fixed by adding 2 lines:

```
proxy_redirect https://example.github.io https://example.com;
proxy_redirect http://example.github.io https://example.com;
```

And btw, if you want to host Jekyll/Ghost on Github Pages, make sure your posts' permalink end in `/`, or it will cost another 301..

Add server side push for css file if using Jekyll, on `server` block:

```
add_header Link '</css/main.css>; rel=preload; as=stylesheet';
```